# How to select an element that have a classname and add to an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, element

I have this html code,

```
<div id=menu>
 <div class=other></div>
 <div class=select></div>
 <div class=select></div>
</div>
```

how can I select all div that have classname of "select" and add it to an array?

I tried this code but not do what I expected,

```
var arr = document.getElementById('menu').children;
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
 if(arr[i].className=='select'){ 
  //do following
 }
}
```

Comment: Use `getElementsByClassName('select')`..

Comment: how can i add it to an array?

Comment: Use Array `push` functionality

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#menu > .select'), 0)` supported by IE8+

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementsByClassName(classname)` as such:

```
selectdivs = document.getElementsByClassName('select')
```

Since the function returns a list.

Or, you could create a blank list and push the valid `div`s:

```
all = []
for(var i = 0;i < document.getElementById("menu").children.length;i++){
    div=document.getElementById("menu").children[i];
    if(div.className == "select"){
         all.push(div)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another array to store required elements:

```
var arr = document.getElementById('menu').children;
var eleArray = [];
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
 if(arr[i].className=='select'){ 
  eleArray.push(arr[i]);
 }
}
```

If it's needless to find for the children of `menu`, you can directly use `document.getElementsByClassName('select')` which returns an array of all the elements with class `select`.